# Performance of F# Array.reduce

Tags: performance, f#

I noticed while doing some F# experiments that if write my own reduce function for Array that it performs much better than the built in reduce. For example:

```
type Array with
    static member inline fastReduce f (values : 'T[]) =
        let mutable result = Unchecked.defaultof<'T>
        for i in 0 .. values.Length-1 do
            result  <- f result values.[i]
        result
```

This seems to behave identically to the built in `Array.reduce` but is ~2x faster for simple `f`

Is the built in one more flexible in some way?

Comment: Yours is basically the same as the core lib except for inline https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/8dcf06f949dc9d05d35aa6bab0fbbd4911d480f3/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs#L785  I imagine particularly if f is inline this could make a difference

Comment: I see, so potentially there could be cases where the inline would harm performance. I'll have to experiment with that.

Comment: Not performance-wise but yours behave differently that the original `Array.reduce` for an empty array (exception vs default value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By looking at the generated IL code it's easier to understand what's happening.

Using the built-in `Array.reduce`:

```
let reducer (vs : int []) : int = Array.reduce (+) vs
```

Gives the following equivalent C# (reverse engineered from the IL code using `ILSpy`)

```
public static int reducer(int[] vs)
{
  return ArrayModule.Reduce<int>(new Program.BuiltIn.reducer@31(), vs);
}
```

`Array.reduce` looks like this:

```
public static T Reduce<T>(FSharpFunc<T, FSharpFunc<T, T>> reduction, T[] array)
{
  if (array == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
  }
  int num = array.Length;
  if (num == 0)
  {
    throw new ArgumentException(LanguagePrimitives.ErrorStrings.InputArrayEmptyString, "array");
  }
  OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<T, T, T> fSharpFunc = OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<T, T, T>.Adapt(reduction);
  T t = array[0];
  int num2 = 1;
  int num3 = num - 1;
  if (num3 >= num2)
  {
    do
    {
      t = fSharpFunc.Invoke(t, array[num2]);
      num2++;
    }
    while (num2 != num3 + 1);
  }
  return t;
}
```

Notice that it invoking the reducer function `f` is a virtual call which typically the JIT:er struggles to inline.

Compare to your `fastReduce` function:

```
let reducer (vs : int []) : int = Array.fastReduce (+) vs
```

The reverse-engineered C# code:

```
public static int reducer(int[] vs)
{
  int num = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < vs.Length; i++)
  {
    num += vs[i];
  }
  return num;
}
```

A lot more efficient as the virtual call is now gone. It seems that in this case F# inlines both the code for `fastReduce` as well as `(+)`.

There's some kind of cut-off in F# as more complex reducer functions won't be inlined. I am unsure on the exact details.

Hope this helps

A side-note; `Unchecked.defaultOf` returns `null` values for class types in .NET such as string. I prefer `LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero`.

PS. A common trick for the real performance hungry is to loop towards `0`. In F# that doesn't work for `for-expressions` because of a slight performance bug in how `for-expressions` are generated. In those case you can try to implement the loop using tail-recursion.

Comment: Yeah I reported that bug in for-expressions =)  Or a related one anyway. Don is working on it!